# Google admob GADBannerView Unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, frameworks, admob

After including the GoogleMobileAdvertising.framework in my project, and ensuring that it is found by the search paths, the following line of code still causes an unrecognized selector error.

```
GADBannerView* gadBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
```

Yes, I already have the -ObjC linker flag set.
Yes, I have included all the other required frameworks.
No, this is not a duplicate question.  There is a similar question already posted, but that one **was** a case of a missing -ObjC flag.  This one quite clearly isn't, as that flag is present.

If I split the allocation and initialization onto separate lines.  e.g.

```
GADBannerView* gadBannerView = [GADBannerView alloc];
[gadBannerView initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
```

Then the error occurs on the second line, the initWithAdSize.

The error is

```
[UIApplication window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e888b0
```

Which doesn't make much sense.  Why is the initWithAdSize even calling on "window" as a selector?  The UIApplicationDelegate protocol lists it as a property.

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Even so, the class implementing UIApplicationDelegate in this case does have that property.  I could maybe understand the error if it was

```
[UIApplication setWindow]: unrecognized selector
```

or

```
[UIApplication getWindow]: unrecognized selector
```

But it isn't.

Comment: Have you checked the flag in the lib where you are using admob as well ?

Comment: Better add Exception break point and get right crashing line. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bH1eZ.png

Comment: saurabh goyal Yes, I have checked the flag in both the project and the target.

@NatureFriend That IS the line where the Exception Break Point hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out the answer was in a child class of that delegate.  It had "window" implemented as a member UIWindow* instead of as a property.  So when the AdMob library tried to call the getter on that property, it wasn't there.  Fixing it to implement it correctly as a property (and then fixing everything else in that class that suddenly won't compile because it's trying to access the property as a member) fixes the Unrecognized Selector error.

I will admit to a certain degree of satisfaction that the delegate in question was not my code.